# getMonth() minus something is giving weird results

Tags: javascript, date

I have a code in which I am testing the difference in months between two dates. To get old date I am doing following thing

```
  var oldDate = new Date();
  oldDate.setMonth(oldDate.getMonth() - 5);
```

But `monthsOldDate` is returning something else and not five month old date why is this behaving weirdly today? and how shall I fix this?

Comment: It is becous getMonth() - 6 you are geting month -6 from this month

Comment: I strongly advise you to use a more robust and understandable date/time library, such as moment.js, instead of native Javascript Date class. As already said, setMonth "sets" the month to the value specifies, which should be a number between 0 to 11 inclusive, and here you are trying to set it to -2.

Comment: @Teemu Please execute the code in chrome dev tool.

Comment: I didn't say it wouldn't work, I asked does it make sense ...

Comment: That is working as expected, What is your desired output?

Comment: `monthsOldDate.getMonth() - 6`  should not be returning "1 Dec 2017", it should return a number.

Comment: Yes because it reverts back to previous year and sets the month accordingly. It worked in Jan/Feb/March/Apr too. It was working till yesterday. Today it broke.

Comment: @Pac0 I mean `monthsOldDate` value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because it's the 31st.

When you call the `setMonth()` method with the argument `-2`, it sets the date to 31 Nov 2017. That's not an actual date, so it gets converted to 1 Dec 2017.

See the [last paragraph of the `Description` section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setMonth) for an explanation of this behavior.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. What is the fix to it?

Comment: Assuming you don't care about the particular day, one approach would be calling `setDate(1)` before calling `setMonth()`. Then you'll avoid the edge case of the current month being longer than the past month.

Comment: Actually I do care. I am passing old date and current date to calculate the difference between  then in months.

Comment: @PabloEscobar but a "month" is not a fixed unit of measure - how are you supposed to handle these cases ? In any case, nothing prevents you from saving the correct date and do some of your business calculations

Comment: I'd need more context to suggest another solution. As it stands, with the example you provided, you're providing the difference in months in the first place (i.e. the `6` in `monthsOldDate.getMonth() - 6`) , so why do you need to calculate it?

Answer (score 1):

> When trying to add or subtract months from a Javascript Date() Object
>   which is an end date of a month, JS automatically advances your Date
>   object to next month’s first date if the resulting date does not exist
>   in its month.

I would recommend using a library like momentjs for this

You can do this by

```
var monthsOldDate = moment().subtract(6, 'months');

console.log(monthsOldDate.month()) //will log 10 (November)
monthsOldDate = monthsOldDate.set("month", monthsOldDate.month())
console.log(monthsOldDate.format("Do MMMM YYYY"))  //30th November 2017
```